# In this sentence, is "this morning" correct with past perfect tense?

Tags: grammaticality, tense, past-perfect

> "I had come to your house this morning."

In this sentence, is "this morning" correct with past perfect tense?

Comment: "I had [already] come to your house [this morning] when the bus crashed into mine." The *already* helps, but when you are discussing a sequence of events in the past, often you really do need the pluperfect.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - indeed!  A lot can happen in a short time!

Comment: If you are simply saying what you did, can't you just say: *I came to your house this morning.* Unless something else happened and you want to include it in your statement. Well, just a thought :D

Comment: @Zakiya. I feel like the OP had wanted to emphasize that this had been her second trip.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, strictly speaking, "this morning" could be correct in that sentence with the past perfect tense.

However, it is not likely that a sentence like that would ever occur in isolation. There should be more information in the sentence itself (or in the conversation that the sentence is part of) that describes some other past event which occurred after the event in the sentence.

The past perfect is *always used **in combination*** with another perfect-tense verb (most commonly, with a verb in the simple past). If the other verb is not included in the same sentence, it should be understood from the context of the conversation or the passage in which the sentence occurs.

> example 1:
>
> > girlfriend:  Why didn't you come to my house this afternoon?
> >
> > boyfriend: (I didn't come to your house this afternoon because) I had (already) come to your house this morning.
>
> example 2:
>
> > I had come to your house this morning *when* I realized that I had left the package at my office.

^ In both of these examples, there was a past event that occurred following an even earlier event:

*I did not come to your house this afternoon* (**past event**-->simple past)

*I had* (already) *come to your house this morning* (**even earlier event**-->past perfect)

...

*I realized I had left the package at my office* (**past event**-->simple past)

*I had come to your house this morning* (**even earlier event**-->past perfect)

> example 3:
>
> > I had finished by the time he was arriving.

*he was arriving* (**past event**-->in this case, past continuous)

*I had finished* (**even earlier event**-->past perfect)